# How do I view an SSL certificate on my iPad from Safari?

Tags: ios, ipad, ipados, encryption

I'm trying to view the SSL certificate for a web site on my iPad.

For example, how can I view the SSL certificate for this site?

https://encrypted.google.com/

Using Safari on the desktop, I can click on the small lock icon in the address bar to view the certificate details.

How do I do this on the iPad?

Answer (score 21):

There is also a free app TLS Inspector. Works fine too. See https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tls-inspector/id1100539810?mt=8

Comment: just what I needed. Good way to validate if you made any DNS changes ( as it shows the cert and the IP underneath the hostname )

Comment: There is another freeware [Inspect - View TLS certificate](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/inspect-view-tls-certificate/id1074957486).

Comment: *TLS Inspector* also adds a convenient feature to view the certificate straight from Safari: tap the Share button and scroll down to the *Show Certificate* option

Answer (score 7):

I believe this feature does not yet exist in Mobile Safari -- probably because it's not in high demand, so it's not high on the development priority list.

Try submitting a feature request through the official Safari feedback form (select "iOS" as your operating system so they know you're referring to Mobile Safari): http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

Comment: Is this still true in iOS 10?

Comment: @lpacheco As far as I know, it's still not possible to view SSL certs in Safari on iOS 10.  Somewhat surprising since so many sites are using them now.  You could try the SSL Detective app mentioned in the 2015 answer by Teecee, but the reviews for it are mixed (a polite way of saying two-thirds of reviewers have given it one star since its last update 20 months ago).

Comment: Still not possible natively in 2023 (iOS 16)...

Answer (score 4):

There is an app "SSL Detective". Many professional IT colleagues use this tool:

- https://twocanoes.com/products/ios/ssl-detective/

You can download the SSL Detective app from the Apple app store.  It lets you connect to a URL on a port you specify and it will show you the certificates associated with that site (if any).  An in-app purchase will apparently show more details on the certificates (I didn't purchase the upgrade as the free version worked for my need).

Comment: I've added a link to the tool and my knowledge that many professionals use and trust this app. The free version is functional and I feel the reviews in the  App Store are a bit harsh - so I've put up a review there as well. It's 5 star software in my opinion.