# How do I view the TLS certificate in iOS 15 Safari?

Tags: ios, safari, certificate, mobile-safari

How do I view the TLS certificate in iOS 15 Safari?

I tried every button on the tool bar, and still couldn't find the view cert option.

Comment: Have you tried one of these options ?
https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13308/how-do-i-view-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-ipad-from-safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use a free app for this: **[TLS Inspector](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tls-inspector/id1100539810)**.

It lets you view details about a domain's certificate and other security-related information.

It also adds a convenient feature to view the certificate straight from Safari:

1. tap the *Share* button
2. scroll down to the *Show Certificate* option